# How to manage sessions on common database for multiple servers in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I will have multiple servers to host my PHP web application. So I can't store session on server, instead of it I need to store session in database. Because it will be common for all servers. That's the way users' session will be maintained, no matter which server the user connects to with each request.
Now the question is how is it possible, suggest me the best option.

Thanks for your support!!!

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/e.zimuel/how-to-scale-php-applications slide 14, use redis, memcached or nfs

Comment: But I didn't understand where should I use this function session_set_save_handler()???